# Understanding a FastICA implementation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, feature-detection

I'm trying to implement FastICA (independent component analysis) for blind signal separation of images, but first I thought I'd take a look at some examples from Github that produce good results. I'm trying to compare the main loop from the algorithm's steps on [Wikipedia's FastICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastICA#Single_component_extraction) and I'm having quite a bit of difficulty seeing how they're actually the same.

They look very similar, but there's a few differences that I don't understand. It looks like this implementation is similar to (or the same as) the "Multiple component extraction" version from Wiki.

Would someone please help me understand what's going on in the four or so lines having to do with the nonlinearity function with its first and second derivatives, and the first line of updating the weight vector? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the implementation with the variables changed to mirror the Wiki more closely:

```
% X is sized (NxM, 3x50K) mixed image data matrix (one row for each mixed image) 

C=3; % number of components to separate                       

W=zeros(numofIC,VariableNum); % weights matrix  

for p=1:C       

    % initialize random weight vector of length N             
    wp = rand(C,1);                   
    wp = wp / norm(wp);  

    % like do:
    i = 1;
    maxIterations = 100; 
    while i <= maxIterations+1

       % until mat iterations 
       if i == maxIterations    
            fprintf('No convergence: ', p,maxIterations); 
            break; 
        end 

        wp_old = wp; 

        % this is the main part of the algorithm and where
        % I'm confused about the particular implementation

        u = 1; 
        t = X'*b; 
        g = t.^3; 
        dg = 3*t.^2; 
        wp = ((1-u)*t'*g*wp+u*X*g)/M-mean(dg)*wp;

        % 2nd and 3rd wp update steps make sense to me   
        wp = wp-W*W'*wp;                       
        wp = wp / norm(wp);  

        % or until w_p converges
        if abs(abs(b'*bOld)-1)<1e-10      
             W(:,p)=b;                  
             break; 
         end 

        i=i+1;         
    end 
end
```

And the Wiki algorithms for quick reference:

[image]

Comment: Well right after I opened this bounty I figured out my misunderstanding :/ Go ahead and answer anyway if you want some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't understand why the term that is always zero remains in the code:

```
wp = ((1-u)*t'*g*wp+u*X*g)/M-mean(dg)*wp;
```

The above can be simplified into:

```
wp = X*g/M-mean(dg)*wp;
```

Also removing `u` since it is always 1.

Second, I believe the following line is wrong:

```
t = X'*b;
```

The correct expression is:

```
t = X'*wp;
```

---

Now let's go through each variable here. Let's refer to

> **w** = *E*{**X****g**(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**)<sup>T</sup>} - *E*{*g*'(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**)}**w**

as the iteration equation.

- `X` is your input data, i.e. **X** in the iteration equation.
- `wp` is the weight vector, i.e. **w** in the iteration equation. Its initial value is randomised.
- `g` is the first derivative of a nonquadratic nonlinear function, i.e. *g*(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**) in the iteration equation
- `dg` is the first derivative of `g`, i.e. *g*'(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**) in the iteration equation
- `M` although its definition is not shown in the code you provide, but I think it should be the size of `X`.

---

Having the knowledge of the meaning of all variables, we can now try to understand the codes.

```
    t = X'*b;
```

The above line computes **w**<sup>T</sup>**X**.

```
    g = t.^3;
```

The above line computes *g*(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**) = (**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**)<sup>3</sup>. Note that *g(u)* can be any equation as long as *f(u)*, where *g(u) = df(u)/du*, is nonlinear and nonquadratic.

```
    dg = 3*t.^2;
```

The above line computes the derivative of `g`.

```
    wp = X*g/M-mean(dg)*wp;
```

`Xg` obviously calculates **X****g**(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**). `Xg/M` calculates the average of `Xg`, which is equivalent to E{**X****g**(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**)<sup>T</sup>}.

`mean(dg)` is *E*{*g*'(**w**<sup>T</sup>**X**)} and multiplies by `wp` or **w** in the equation.

Now you have what you needed for Newton-Raphson Method.

Comment: Thanks. So one thing I'm still unsure about is the output. It says `S=W'X` where`X` is the centered/whitened data, but this doesn't give a good result. I have to do `S = 50*W'*WhiteningMat*Uncentered_Unwhitened_Data` to  produce pictures that look correct. Any Idea why this is?

Comment: Actually have to do  `S = abs(50*W'*WhiteningMat*Uncentered_Unwhitened_Data)`

Comment: @Jake Because you reduce the "luminance" of the picture after applying the weight factor.

Comment: For the const part? Why do I need to use the whitened but uncentered version of the data and also take the absolute value? It seems different from the notation in the Wiki.

Comment: Pure mathematically, you can apply **w** to the centred data, i.e. **X**, but you have to uncentre the outcome, which is not quite possible. This can be verified if you try `S = W'*WhiteningMat*UncenteredUnwhitenedData; SMean = mean(S); S_centredThenUncentred = W'*X+SMean;`, `S` should equal `S_centredThenUncentred`. You might have to modify the expressions for calculating the mean and uncentring.

Comment: @Jake I think the question you asked in your comment is more related to the math and theory behind the code rather than the code itself, which means it is beyond the scope of your original question. I'm also not familiar with ICA (only started to look at it yesterday) and it is difficult for me to understand it in a short time without any background knowledge in signal processing. I would suggest you start a new question somewhere else, maybe [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In addition, I want to correct myself that it is NOT the weight that reduces the "luminance". It is because ICA cannot restore the magnitude of the original signal. I read this [here](http://arnauddelorme.com/ica_for_dummies/).

Comment: Thanks I think I understand everything except for why I need to take the absolute value. Any idea about that part?

Comment: Going to award you the bounty by the way, but it says I need to wait 2 hours.

Comment: @Jake thanks for your upvotes. I found [some slides](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2007/cmsc818z/V%20Surat%20Chaitanya_818Z.pdf) and [a journal paper](https://researchbank.rmit.edu.au/eserv/rmit:1577/n2006005092.pdf) both mentioning one limitation of the ICA which is the sign of output cannot be determined. For images, the solution is quite simple. Since negative rgb values do not exist, simply take the absolute values. Doc 1 seems to be a quite good lecture on ICA. I will probably read it later :).

Comment: My pleasure @Jake.